# Is there an ASP.NET Boilerplate Way of getting JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, aspnetboilerplate

I am currently trying this, but I keep seeing the dreaded error:

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

[image]

I am struggling to find a solution and was wondering if anyone has any tips on how to solve this?

**The class being serialized to JSON:**

```
[Serializable]
public class GeoCoordinate
{
    public GeoCoordinate()
    {
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lat")]
    public double Latitude { get; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "long")]
    public double Longitude { get; }

    public GeoCoordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1}", Latitude, Longitude);
    }
}
```

**Ajax call:**

```
function getLocationData() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: abp.appPath + "Home/GetLocationsAsync",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            locations = [];
            $.each(myArray, function (index, element) {
                locations.push([element.lat, element.long]);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetLocationsAsync()
{
    var cords = await _practiceAppService.GetAllGeoCoordinates();
    return Json(cords);
}
```

**AppService:**

```
public async Task<IList<GeoCoordinate>> GetAllGeoCoordinates()
{
    var geoCoordinates = await Repository.GetAll()
        .Where(x => !x.Disabled && !x.Latitude.Equals(0) && !x.Longitude.Equals(0))
        .Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))
        .ToListAsync();

    return geoCoordinates;
}
```

**Console.log** of data before attempted call to `parseJSON`:

```
console.log(data);
var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidentally, there is a section called [The ASP.NET Boilerplate Way](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/AJAX#the-asp-net-boilerplate-way) that exactly addresses this.

Note that only point 2 is specific to ABP:

1. `GetLocationsAsync` returns a JSON object and not a string, so you should not call [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

   You can reproduce the error message with: `jQuery.parseJSON({});`
2. ABP wraps `JsonResult`. From the documentation on [AJAX Return Messages](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/AJAX#ajax-return-messages):

   > This return format is recognized and handled by the **abp.ajax** function.

   You could use `[DontWrapResult]` attribute, but you might as well leverage on ABP here. `abp.ajax` [handles the display of error messages](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/AJAX#handling-errors) if you throw a `UserFriendlyException`.
3. Since `ajax` is asynchronous, `getLocationData` cannot return `locations` directly.

   You can return a chained [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If you're new to Promises, read [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) first.
4. There's a neater way than `$.each` and `push`.

   You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Finally:

```js
function getLocationData() {
    return abp.ajax({
        url: abp.appPath + "Home/GetLocationsAsync",
        type: 'GET'
    }).then(function (result) {
        return result.map(function (element) {
            return [element.lat, element.long];
        });
    });
}
```

Usage:

```js
getLocationData().then(function (locations) {
    console.log(locations);
});
```

Comment: awsome - abp to the rescue once again! thanks @aaron

Comment: I think this is where abp.ajx is defined: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/f10fa5205c780bcc27adfe38aaae631f412eb7df/test/aspnet-core-demo/AbpAspNetCoreDemo/wwwroot/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.jquery.js

Comment: @user703163 Yes.

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET Boilerplate wraps ASP.NET MVC action results by default if the return type is a JsonResult. So if you want to get the result you can disable wrapping. Try adding **[DontWrapResult]** attribute to the **GetLocationsAsync** method.

```
[DontWrapResult]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetLocationsAsync()
{
    var cords = await _practiceAppService.GetAllGeoCoordinates();
    return Json(cords);
}
```

PS: You don't need to add this attribute. You can get it from **result** field. Inspect the response via your browser's dev console to see how it's wrapped.